# How to merge a number of 3-dimensional numpy arrays inside a 4-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, merge, numpy-ndarray

As I have already stated, my question is: how, given an initial 4-dimensional numpy array `A`, to concatinate several 3-d numpy arrays inside `A`, <strike>without using any additional temporary or copy arrays</strike>.

For my program I have to perform the above action in order to group several 3-d numpy arrays together. Say, I have the 4-d numpy array `A = [A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4,..., A_9]`, where each `A_i` is a 3-d numpy array.

Now, for example, I want to merge `A_0, A_2, A_3` into `A_023`, and `A_4, A_9, A_7` into `A_479`, so that the initial 3-d numpy array is now `A = [A_023, A_497, A_5, A_6, A_8]`. (note that I want to sort the elements in A by order of the first digit of `A_ijk`, i.e. by `i`, the latter are not important)

I tried to implement that as follows: given a `key_merge` 2-d numpy array of `key_merge = [[key_0_0, elem_0_1, ..., elem_0_m], [key_1_0, ..., elem_1_c], ...]`, I take the key_i_j value from each array in key_merge and do: `np.concatenate((A[key_i_j], A[elem_0_1]), axis=3)`and so on, but for some reason, this does not work out..

I would appreciate any help of yours, or any hints, as for me this problem is quite hard to solve by myself, as I am new to numpy syntax.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To avoid a copy, the underlying 1d databuffer has to remain the same.  `reshape` is only that can do that.  If the shape is (a,b,c,d), then new shapes like (a*b,c,d) or (a,b*c,d) are possible.  Anything else the involves are reordering of the underlying data requires a copy.  `concatenate` makes a copy.  `transpose` followed by `reshape` makes a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your comment! I think, this may be useful, when merging two in-set neighboring arrays, but what about merging non-neighboring? I actually doubt that then it is even possible to solve my task without creating temporary arrays.